# Java - Application hangs at random spot after rt.exec calls to c++ program for WinXP 32bit

Tags: java, windows, stream, block, runtime.exec

Hello I have a visual studio 2008 c++ project that communicates through COM1 to a custom device. Testing shows it works as expected (when used from cmd.exe), it sends some data (sent to it through args) and prints (cout) the next 300 bytes it reads from the port.

example:

> cppprogram.exe -send RANDOM_HEXSTRING_HERE -C COM1
>   [0000FFABCD1873295287210173983198396918273 (...) 1278612851FFEB]

The format of the reply is always [hexstring]. In case of error it returns -1, otherwise 0. When executed on cmd.exe, you can see it prints "slowly", ~100 bytes, a second wait, another 100, and so on, depending on the speed the external device generates data. But it always ends since the device is always printing and the program only waits for 300 bytes.

To build on top of this "system" I am doing a program in Java. It is supposed to send query after query to the device and process the outputs. I use the cpp program as intermediary.

For each type of query I have a function, there are many types of queries, but the code for each function is similar, only the hex string query and the strings I look for in the final output changes, queries to the device are not run in parallel, the program is supposed to run sequentially. The (current) code is as follows:

Main.java

```
main()
{
    (...)
    while( keepgoing )
    {
        (...)
        print( start Query A )
        QueryDeviceA()
        print( end Query A )
        (...)
    }
    (...)
}

public String QueryDeviceA()
{
    try
    {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec( "cppprogram.exe -C COM1 -rq" ); //rq performs the query A without having to put the hexstring    

        // any error message?
//      StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString errorGobbler = new StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString( pr.getErrorStream(), "ERR" );

        // any output?
        StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString outputGobbler = new StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString( pr.getInputStream(), "OUT" );

        // kick them off
System.out.println( "1" );
        System.out.flush();
        outputGobbler.start();
//      errorGobbler.start();

        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();

        outputGobbler.join();
//      errorGobbler.join();
        System.out.flush();
System.out.println( "2" );

        String returnValue = outputGobbler.getReturnValue();
        rt.gc();
System.out.println( "3" );

        if( returnValue == null ) return null;

        int start = returnValue.indexOf("[");
        int end = returnValue.indexOf("]", start);

        boolean datafound = false;
        if( start > -1 && end > -1 )
        {
            String returnpart = returnValue.substring(start+1, end);
            if( returnpart == null ) return null;

            start = 0;
            while( start < returnpart.length() )
            {
                do { start = returnpart.indexOf("0103", start); } while( start % 2 > 0 && start != -1 );
                if( start == -1 ) break;
                start+=2;

                do { end = returnpart.indexOf("04", start); } while( end % 2 > 0 && end != -1 );
                if( end == -1 ) break;
System.out.println( "4" );
                returnValue = TranslateEscapedData(returnpart.substring(start, end)); //doesnt have infinite loops
System.out.println( "5" );
                if( returnValue.length() != 30 ) continue;
                if( !"040F20".equals( returnValue.substring(12,18) ) ) continue;
System.out.println( "6" );
                //Verify Checksum
                if( !ValidChecksum(returnValue) ) continue; //doesnt have infinite loops
System.out.println( "7" );
                returnpart = returnValue.substring(18,26);
                datafound = true;
                break;
            }

            if( !datafound ) return null;
            return returnpart;
        }

        return null;
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

StreamGobbler.java

```
public class StreamGobbler extends Thread
{
    public InputStream is;
    public String type;
    public OutputStream os;

    private StreamGobbler()
    {
    }

    public StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type)
    {
        this(is, type, null);
    }

    public StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type, OutputStream redirect)
    {
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
        this.os = redirect;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter pw = null;
            if( os != null ) pw = new PrintWriter(os);

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
            {
                if( pw != null ) pw.println(line);
                //System.out.println( type + ">" + line );
            }
            if( pw != null ) pw.flush();
        }
        catch( IOException ioe )
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString.java

```
public class StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString extends util.StreamGobbler
{
    private String returnValue;

    public StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString(InputStream is, String type)
    {
        this(is, type, null);
    }

    public StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString(InputStream is, String type, OutputStream redirect)
    {
        super( is, type, redirect );
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter pw = null;
            if( os != null ) pw = new PrintWriter(os);

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
            {
                if( pw != null ) pw.println(line);
                //System.out.println( type + ">" + line );
                returnValue += line;
            }
            if( pw != null ) pw.flush();
            //br.close();
        }
        catch( IOException ioe )
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the returnValue
     */
    public String getReturnValue() {
        return returnValue;
    }

    /**
     * @param returnValue the returnValue to set
     */
    public void setReturnValue(String returnValue) {
        this.returnValue = returnValue;
    }
}
```

As you can see I am using print debugging because the production pc (with the external device) has no debugging tools and is far away. I execute this java program using a *.bat file and dragging it to an open cmd.exe window, it starts to display information sent via System.out.println, it displays the debug lines for a few other queries (about five, with pauses since the external program takes a second or so to finish the 300 byte output), until it gets to Query A, and, currently, stops at "3", forever. I look at the code, and I see no reason to stop at 3.

The Gobbler is copy pasted code, its the usual while( ( line = br.readline() ) != null ).

I've put the joins before the waitFor, added 10000 millis timeout to them, to just one of them, commented out the error stream since the -rq query isn't getting errors anyway, added those system.out.flush, had a system.out.println(line) on the gobbler while loop. And it only changes the debug line printed before hanging forever or some other error that seems more logical to me. eg. If I comment out the thread joins, I usually get the full output, but sometimes it isn't complete, I assume because I'm reading gobbler's result before it is done working, and that's why I'm adding the joins.

When I use system.out.println within the gobbler's loop the hang seems to show up on an earlier query, so my only lead is there, but this is obviously out of my current knowledge so the question here :) I put a print at the start and end of both gobblers' run method, and both seem to start and end well.

The code is currently running on java 1.6.0_23-b05, Windows XP SP 2, the configurations on the production machine(s) are effectively random and out of my reach, but if it is related to them I could just add that note and shrug it off I guess.

edit: The stream reader that works just to have something useful...

```
public String Query()
{
    try
    {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec( "cppprogram.exe -C COM1 -rq" );

        // any error message?
        StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString errorGobbler = new StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString( pr.getErrorStream(), "ERR" );

        // any output?
        StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString outputGobbler = new StreamGobbleAndReturnAsString( pr.getInputStream(), "OUT" );

        // kick them off
        outputGobbler.start();
        errorGobbler.start();

        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();

        outputGobbler.join();
        errorGobbler.join();

        String returnValue = outputGobbler.getReturnValue();
        rt.gc();

        if( exitVal == 0 ) //success
        {}
        else //cppprogram.exe returned error, do we care?
        {}

        if( returnValue == null ) return null;

        //process returnValue further if needed and then
        return returnValue;
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this line of your "Main.java":

```
do { start = returnpart.indexOf("0103", start); } while( start % 2 > 0 && start != -1 );
```

Let's say we have a string like

```
returnpart = "x0103";
```

The first time, we'll call

```
returnpart.indexOf("0103", start);
```

with `start` equal to 1.  `start % 2` is 1 and `start` will be 1, so the loop continues.

Now we make the call, and get `start` still equal to 1, and so the loop will never terminate.  I think that off-by-one error is your problem, and explains why it doesn't happen every time (it depends on the output of the other program).

Comment: damn i missed that, hopefully its just that

Comment: yeah it was, can't believe it hadn't shown before... ended with

    while( true )
    {
     start = returnpart.indexOf("0103", start);
     if( start == -1 ) break;
     if( start % 2 == 0 ) break;
     ++start;
    }
    if( start == -1 ) break;
    start+=2;

    end = start;
    while(true)
    {
     end = returnpart.indexOf("04", end);
     if( end == -1 ) break;
     if( end % 2 == 0 ) break;
     ++end;
    }
    if( end == -1 ) break;